# @PostConstruct not running within Spring test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I have a `Service` class with a `@PostConstruct` method that should init a param.

Then a regular method is using this param. Even though in a regular run this works as expected, during the unit testing the `@PostConstruct` is skipped and the param is not initialized.

I guess this is something really stupid:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

private String s;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    s = "a";
}

public String append(String a){
    return s+ a;
}
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  //  <------- tried with and without
public class MyServiceTest {

@Test
public void testXYZ(){
    Assertions.assertThat(new MyService().append("b")).isEqualTo("ab");
}

}
```

Run results (when running from IntelliJ - right click and run test, or when running via console of `gradle test`):

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
   <"nullb">
to be equal to:
   <"ab">
but was not.
Expected :"ab"
Actual   :"nullb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an object manually using `new` keyword, `@PostConstruct` method is called by Spring DI containeron components managed by Spring so it will not work on objects created manually.

This one will work as you expect:

```java
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testXYZ(){
        Assertions.assertThat(service.append("b")).isEqualTo("ab");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the `MyService` bean coming from in this snippet?

Comment: What does `@SpringBootTest` do? Does it perform a component scan? Will that scan include the package their `MyService` class is in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis SpringBootTest creates an entire spring context and is for unit tests massively redundant and slow.

Comment: @Gimby Will that context create/contain a `MyService` bean?

Comment: @nkrivenko Thanks! The missing part in my code was the `@SpringBootTest` and the `@Autowire`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, and everything else. All beans, all related services, database context, etc. etc.

Comment: I don't think that's right. Unless these classes are in the same package, and I doubt a test class is in the same package as some service class, the `@SpringBootTest` shouldn't be component scanning it.